# WebGLRenderer Context Lost Issue in Chrome and Edge

Tags: google-chrome, browser, webgl, microsoft-edge, web3js

Encountering a rendering issue on our website in Chrome and Edge, displaying the error: THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost. The website works fine in Firefox. 
GitHub Link - https://github.com/ReyKan-KP/portfolio 
Website Link - https://portfolio-kanishaka-pranjal.vercel.app

Error - [Console of Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EzqL.png)

Expected Smooth rendering in all major browsers.
[Console Of Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y5pq.png)

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether this website is opened on remote desktop?

Comment: Questions here must be self-contained. Please [edit] a [mre] directly into your question. See [ask].

Comment: @ElinLu The website is operational when used on a locally within Firefox, but it encounters the same mentioned above issues when accessed through Chrome and Edge browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I can reproduce your issue on my side.

I think this issue seems to be related to Chromium-based browsers, and I recommend you could report the issue [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) for more help.